# weka doesnot show arff feature values

Tags: weka, arff

I have an .arff file with 5 features named:

```
JaccardCoefficient,adamicadar,commonneighbors,katz,rootedpagerank
```

I open the file in weka but it does not show katz values. It shows the max:0 min:0 mean:0 stddev:0
Note that the katz values are so small like 0.0000312.  What should I do to see katz values?

Comment: Can you show a shortened version of the arff file?

Comment: I cannot share the file(my dropbox doesnot have public sharing),can I have your email address to send you my file?This is my email :Lalemadahali@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at your sample file in Weka and have found the zero values that were reported.  The data appears to be visually represented correctly, but the precision of the attributes appear to be limited to three decimal places.  For this reason, the values are too small to be represented in the attribute list.

One way that you could change this for use with Weka's prediction models is to pre-process the data to a more suitable range.  This could be done using normalisation or other rescaling techniques as required for your purposes.  In the image below, I have adjusted the data by simply multiplying the attribute by 100, which brought the attribute summaries into a visible range on the screen:

[image]

Hope this helps!